# vue-flickity: how to get selectedIndex into vue data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-flickity

I'm  using [vue-flickity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-flickity) for a carousel. There's a `<flickity />` component (the carousel), a `<p>` tag with data `{{ selectedIndex }}`, and a button which gets the current slide number from `flickity`, and updates `selectedIndex`.

How can I automatically update `selectedIndex` with the current slide index when a user scrolls left or right (i.e. calls [Next/Previous](https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity/blob/master/src/flickity.vue) methods)? I'm struggling to "hook into" those methods of the module.

I can define a method `Next()` and bind that to a button, but it doesn't update when a user scrolls.

**EDIT:** I've managed to hook into `on.change` (using `mounted`). `console.log` shows me the correct `selectedInde` now, but this isn't reacting down to where it says "You are at Slide number {{ selectedIndex }}"

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <flickity ref="flickity" :options="flickityOptions">
      <div class="carousel-cell">1</div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">2</div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">3</div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">4</div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">5</div>
    </flickity>
    <p>You are at Slide number {{ selectedIndex }}</p>
    <button @click="manualUpdate()">Update</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Flickity from 'vue-flickity'

export default {
  components: {
    Flickity
  },
  data() {
    return {
      flickityOptions: {
        initialIndex: 0,
        prevNextButtons: false,
        pageDots: false,
        wrapAround: true
      },
      selectedIndex: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    manualUpdate() {
      this.selectedIndex = this.$refs.flickity.selectedIndex();
      console.log(this.selectedIndex)
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.flickity.on('change', function (event) {
      this.selectedIndex = event
      console.log(this.selectedIndex)
    })
  }
}
</script>

<style>
/* external css: flickity.css */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  max-height: 80vh;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you please double check that `manualUpdate` is being called with a `console.log`? Also, in your devtools you should see some events emitted by flickity, wiring it on a listener `@yourCoolEvent` could fix this issue by calling a method on the emitted listener. Since `$refs` are not reactive in Vue2.

Comment: @kissu yes, confirmed `manualUpdate` works via  `console.log`. I don't see any events firing when I change slide.

Comment: No way, there should be some events firing since it's a vue package. Can you make a [repro] please?

Comment: @kissu I have updated it with the minimal reproducible example. You need the module https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-flickity of course

Comment: @kissu using `mounted`, I've managed to hook into it. It now `console.log`s the slide index, but it's not updating the template. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explain on this [Github issue](https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity/issues/45#issuecomment-465252369), you need to bind the listener on the `init` event.
The end result looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <flickity ref="flickity" :options="flickityOptions" @init="onInit">
      <div class="carousel-cell">1</div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">2</div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">3</div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">4</div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">5</div>
    </flickity>
    <p>You are at Slide number {{ selectedIndex }}</p>
    <button @click="goToPrevious">Previous</button>
    <button @click="goToNext">Next</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Flickity from 'vue-flickity'

export default {
  components: {
    Flickity,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      flickityOptions: {
        initialIndex: 0,
        prevNextButtons: false,
        pageDots: false,
        wrapAround: true,
      },
      selectedIndex: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    goToNext() {
      this.$refs.flickity.next()
    },
    goToPrevious() {
      this.$refs.flickity.previous()
    },
    onInit() {
      this.$refs.flickity.on('change', (event) => {
        this.selectedIndex = event
        console.log('current index', event)
      })
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style>
/* external css: flickity.css */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  max-height: 80vh;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>
```

---

There was indeed no other event, which is super strange and I took the libery to write previous/next buttons rather than keep something manual but you could compute and offset (did not found any method for a direct setter).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. In the end, I used vue-awesome-swiper. I can pass my method (to update data) directly into the component.